# Best practice - Generate HTML with XML and XSL in .Net

Tags: asp.net, xslt

We have an old ASP.Net application which gets data from a database and generates HTML output to present that data using normal ASP.Net features.
Our customer wants better control of the HTML output, and is therefore suggesting that we store data in XML files, and they deliver and XSL file which transforms the XML into the desired HTML.
The produced HTML contains HTML tables, lists, CSS class references and javascript.

My first thought here is what is the need for ASP.Net then? We cannot avoid using it, as a lot of our code is written in C# and ASP.Net. But are there some issues we should keep in mind, as to why not to choose this method? Does anyone out there have experience doing as we are about to do? Will we meet any dead ends that make us incapable of fulfilling the customers' needs? What about performance for example. All those questions popped to my head when I heard about their request.
Any advice is welcomed here
Thanks
Jihad

Answer (score 0):

If presentation is the only problem, you can use a Jquery type framework with HTML5 and better CSS to improve it. There is no reason to go the XML+ XSLT way.
All you will need to do is to change the style/design on the .aspx pages leaving the .cs pages intact.

Comment: The thing is that our customer knows XSLT and XML, and does not know ASPX. So I can reduce my question to: Do you see any problem in the way they are suggesting a solution? I am not so fond of it, mostly because the procedure in which we have to work with the customer will be different, and we will have to depend on them to fix errors, if the errors lie within HTML generation. But other than that, I do not have any arguments against it